# How do I abort RSpec if setup fails?

Tags: ruby, rspec

A really simple question, but one I haven't been able to find an answer to:

I want to write the following in rspec:

```
describe "Some examples" do
    before(:all) do
       if(i_forgot_to_start_some_important_background_service)
           dont_run_any_tests
       end
    end
    ...
end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any special RSpec magic for this - just test that your service is running in your spec_helper.rb, and raise an exception if it's not running.

```
if service_not_running
  raise "Service is not running. Please start it with {whatever}."
end
```

This will cause your rspec suite to immediately fail when it starts, with a helpful error that helps the programmer get the service started.

Comment: This works, but beware: the `after` can run even if `before` raises.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this possible or not but you can stop rspec immediately after failing like this:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.fail_fast = true
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that, but it's not quite what I want.  Tests may fail for other reasons than the background services not being available, and in that case I still want the remaining tests to run.

Answer (score -2):

I think you doing it wrong way  you should really just test the behavior of your class/model and depend that background service are ok at this point (stub or mock them and test your background service in separate test.

or if you uncomfortable with this, test your spec when background service is on and off again by stubbing the result of those services

Comment: if you don't know much about stubing check https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs  or my scrapbook (it's a mess I know ) http://eq8scrapbook.heroku.com/equivalents_scrap/on_rspec  look for keyword "stub"

Comment: It's helpful to know that all the tests failed because background services were not running.  These are integration tests, stubbing is not appropriate.

Comment: I agree that if those are integration tests, he shouldn't stub them, I disagree that their functionality should be triggered as a background process. Let say he use `delayed_job` gem for his background process, he should configure his test environment so that `handle_asynchronously` would process that call without delaying it(simply by adding `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?`) Delayed processing is tested in gem specs itself, he really needs to write tests for his own code only. ...When it comes to unit testing I stand by what I said in my answer.

Comment: ah sorry Stefan I discovered you are the one who asked this :D  ...so you are "he"

Comment: Agreed, for unit tests a different approach would be valid.  For integration tests, I need to check the dependencies.

Comment: yes, and your dependencies are covered  with that approach that I described in prev. comment. The only difference is that they'll be triggered straight away, not by delayed process (which is correct). The whole purpose of delaying stuff is to lighten the server in production mode, you shouldn't work with delaying stuff in test environment